# Mysql Select Timestamp in intervals

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE `TPS_INFO` (
    `TPS` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `AT_TIME` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL 
              DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```

i want to select the TPS Values and timestamps , such that the timestamps are selected in a difference of 1 minute.

How  can i do this in mysql ..

Comment: could you show any results example

Answer (score 0):

```
select *,TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,t1.AT_TIME,t2.AT_TIME) AS diff from tps_info t1 , tps_info  t2 having diff='60'
```

Comment: @SureshKamrushi who is putting this -ve and y dont they comment when they do so???i dont know

Comment: Why are you asking to me!!!. My concern is to solve the problem and not to down vote anybody!!.

Comment: OP wants to create a time series.

Answer (score -1):

Finally i made it, here it goes-

```
Select m.tps,m.at_time from TPS_info m, tps_info c 
where (date_add(m.at_time, INTERVAL 1 MINUTE) = c.at_time) OR
  (date_add(m.at_time, INTERVAL -1 MINUTE) = c.at_time)
group by m.at_time
order by m.at_time
```

initially i try like,

```
Select m.tps,m.at_time from TPS_info m, tps_info c 
where date_add(m.at_time, INTERVAL 1 MINUTE) = c.at_time
```

see the [**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0e6bb/1)

**NOTE :** it's working fine except that last record is not being retrieve.

Same result with

```
Select m.tps,m.at_time from TPS_info m, tps_info c 
where 60 = TIME_TO_SEC( TIMEDIFF( m.at_time, c.at_time ) )
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from TPS_INFO where TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, AT_TIME,NOW()) < 60
```